# Find $\operatorname{Cov}(\frac{1}{C}, D)$ given that $\operatorname{Cov}(\frac{A}{BC}, D) = X $

Tags: statistics, variance, covariance, correlation

> Find $\operatorname{Cov}(\frac{1}{C}, D)$ given that $\operatorname{Cov}(\frac{A}{BC}, D) = X $, where $\operatorname{Cov}$ is the covariance and $\operatorname{Cov}(A, B) = \operatorname{Cov}(A, C) = \operatorname{Cov}(A, D) = \operatorname{Cov}(B, C) = \operatorname{Cov}(B, D) = 0$.

I'm an experimental physicist trying to combine some measurements to determine the covariance between $\frac{1}{C}$ and $D$, but I only know the covariance between $\frac{A}{BC}$ and $D$. $A$ and $B$ are fully uncorrelated and separate factors. I'm not really sure how to do this as I'm not that familiar with the algebra of covariances.

Is it the case that $\operatorname{Cov}(\frac{A}{BC}, D) = \operatorname{Cov}(\frac{1}{C}, D)$ in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Comment: You'll want to be more specific, there's no general formula for this.

Comment: Okay, sorry. In this case, I will quickly edit to make it more specific.

Comment: Is that better? @Aruralreader

Comment: I do not think there is an answer to finding $\operatorname{Cov}(C, D)$ given that $\operatorname{Cov}(\frac{1}{C}, D) = x $, as scaling $C$ and $D$ together means you can achieve any magnitude for $\operatorname{Cov}(C, D)$ even before you consider distributional questions

Comment: HI @Henry, thanks a lot for your answer. Knowing $\operatorname{Cov}(\frac{1}{C}, D)$ would probably suffice in this case actually. Am I correct in saying that you are saying that $\operatorname{Cov}(\frac{1}{C}, D) = \operatorname{Cov}(\frac{AB}{C}, D) $ if $A$ and $B$ are fully uncorrelated? I don't need to factor $A$ and $B$ into the calculation somehow?

Comment: No - I am suggesting that your question may not have an answer, as a simpler version with $A$ and $B$ both constant and equal to $1$ also seems as if it may not have an answer

Comment: Okay, then maybe a simpler question might be given $\operatorname{Cov}(\frac{AB}{C}, D) = x$ and with full information (means, variances) about the totally uncorrelated variables $A$ and $B$, what is the expression for $\operatorname{Cov}(\frac{1}{C}, D)$?

Comment: @Henry, that's a good way to look at it. If $A$ and $B$ both are constants, they'll have $\text{cov}(A, B) = 0$ and you'll be left with trying to estimate $\text{cov}(C, D)$ from $\text{cov}(1/C, D)$, which I don't see a way to do.

Comment: @Aruralreader Is it possible to determine $\operatorname{Cov}(\frac{1}{C}, D)$ given that $\operatorname{Cov}(\frac{A}{BC}, D) = X $ then, in this case? I'm wondering whether one can just ignore $A$ and $B$ as they are totally uncorrelated.